# Android Dynamic Autocomplete don't show

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

i need help with my code, i try to implement aoutocomplete textview but don't work.

i used a asyntask and a httpclient to catch the info from google.

My code is:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
AutoCompleteTextView text_search;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text_search = (AutoCompleteTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tx_search);


    ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Dowgo"));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entries);



    text_search.setAdapter(adapter);
    text_search.setThreshold(1);

    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);



    text_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {



            new AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>(){

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    text_search.setAdapter(null);
                }

                @Override
                protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
                    int lon = strings.length;
                    if (lon<1) return null;

                    String busqueda = strings[0];
                    String url = "http://clients1.google.com/complete/search";

                    if (busqueda.length() < 2) return null;

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


                    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0");

                    if(!url.endsWith("?"))
                        url += "?";

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();


                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", busqueda));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nolabels", "t"));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client", "youtube"));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ds", "yt"));

                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

                    url += paramString;


                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

                    //httpget.addHeader("Accept-Language", "es");

                    ArrayAdapter adaptador;
                    try {



                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);


                        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) return null;

                        HttpEntity resEntityGet = response.getEntity();

                        String respuesta = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);



                        respuesta = respuesta.substring(respuesta.indexOf("[["), respuesta.indexOf("]]") + 2);


                        String[] resultados = respuesta.split(",");

                        int lens = 0;

                        if(resultados.length%2==0)  lens = resultados.length/2;
                        else lens = (resultados.length-1)/2;

                        String[] sugeridos = new String[lens];

                        int con = 0;
                        for(int x=0;x<resultados.length-1;x+=2){
                            sugeridos[con] = resultados[x].replace("[","").replace("\"","");
                            con++;
                        }

                        Log.d("Respuesta",respuesta);


                        return  sugeridos;

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        return null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return null;
                    }


                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

                    if (result != null){



                        adapter.clear();
                        for(int x=0;x<result.length;x++) {
                            adapter.add(result[x]);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        text_search.showDropDown();
                    }else{

                        adapter.clear();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }



                }

            }.execute(charSequence.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you getting an error? What's happening when you run your application? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger, and if so, what are you expecting to see and where is your application departing from that?

Comment: I think you need to repeat text_search.setAdapter(adapter); when you update your adapter. Repeat it at the end of onPostExecutr

Comment: Thank you Stevan it work, sorry for my bad english, i add this lines:

                        text_search.setAdapter(adapter);
                        text_search.showDropDown();

onPostExecutr, thank you again. ;)